# Printring string through loop

Tags: c, string, for-loop

i am working on a school project and i need to enter the national teems for a backetball tournament. I need to enter 3 teams, and when i have a problem with printing, this is just a test print, i kicks me out of a program, this is in C language. Best Regards.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
    char t[30];

    int score1, score2;

    int i;

    printf("Enter the National Teams\n");
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", &t[i]);
    }
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("%s", t[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're creating a char array of size 30 and trying to store separate char arrays in individual char locations. That's like pouring a 10 gallon jug of milk into a teacup. If you didn't quite get that, strings in C are null-terminated char arrays.

Comment: So what size should i put? thanks for the answer

Comment: Did you learn pointers yet? They work wonders when using strings. If not, use a 2d char array of size [N][Y] where N is the max number of strings and Y is the max length of your strings.

Comment: I have a bit problem undesrtanding it since my english in terms of programming slang is bag, can you somehow tell me what to do? Thanks again

Comment: Haha its funny cuz we learnt pointers today, ill search it, but if you could tell me what to do with pointers i would appretiate it, since im in a hurry, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `2-D char array` as follows :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char t[30][30];
    int score1, score2;
    int i;

    printf("Enter the National Teams\n");
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", t[i]);
    }
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("%s", t[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

2-D char array t[X][Y] : X is the max number of strings and Y is the max length of string possible

Comment: @JulianCosta If your issue has been solved, accept the appropriate answer so that it would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

The big thing to remember is that strings in C are arrays of type `char`, with a null terminator character (ASCII 0) at the end. What you've done here is to declare a `char` array of length 30. Your program is trying to shovel a string (which is a `char` array) into each slot in the array, resulting in a crash.

What you really want is to create an array of arrays of `char`s (otherwise known as a 2D array), and store one string in each slot of that (and print it again afterwards).

To clarify, think of an array like a series of buckets, each of which can contain one value (in this case, a `char`):

`[ ][ ][c][ ][a]`

What your program is trying to do is shove a whole string (which is a whole bunch of `char`s) into each bucket:

```
[a][ ][ ][ ][ ]
 z
 c
 f
 b
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int i;

  char (*teamName)[10];

  for ( i=0; i < 3; i++ ){
    scanf("%s", &teamName[i]);
  }

  for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
    printf("%s\n", teamName[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It does the exact same thing as the 2D array suggestion below, but it uses pointers to do it.